# Как обновить дорожный трафик(avoidTrafficJams) чтобы с false он перешел в true&

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, обновление, яндекс-карта-api

Трафик не включается, при нажатии кнопки на балуне

```
 document.getElementById('toggle-traffic-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
                      
                    route.model.setParams({ avoidTrafficJams: !avoidTrafficJams }, true);
                   
                });
```

Comment: Добавление в балун активных кнопок описано в примере о настройке балуна метки https://clck.ru/39P5H8 , а функция переключения пробок на примере построения маршрута https://clck.ru/39P5KV . Если объединение выполнить не удалось, покажите минимальный пример кода, где можно воспроизвести ситуацию.